# Preons as scalar-like fermions?

Tags: particle-physics, beyond-the-standard-model

The symmetry of the standard model between the fermions and each generation of them is strongly suggestive of components as proposed in the [Rishon model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishon_model). Having discovered the Higgs boson, we know the Higgs plays a strong role in the mass of the fermions. Having heard of vector-like fermions, is there something that could be called a scalar-like fermion?  Is it possible for Rishon fermions to exist with scalar properties to act like a Higgs boson and provide a substructure to fermions that obeys the standard model?